# Undefined variable: gejala (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller :

```
 public function TampilGejala(){
    $data['gejala'] = $this->model_admin->tampil_gejala();
    $this->load->view('auth/admin_gejala',$data);
  
}
```

Models:

```
public function tampil_gejala() {
    return $this->db->get('gejala')->result_array();
   
}
```

View :

```
<?php 
                            foreach($gejala as $g){ 
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $g->kode_gejala ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $g->nama_gejala ?></td>
                                <td>Button</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Mysql:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYwwh.png)

**Can you help me ?**

Comment: you have load model in controller??

Comment: yes, i have , but it doesn't work

Comment: public function TampilGejala(){
        $data['gejala'] = $this->model_admin->tampil_gejala();
        $this->load->model('model_admin');
        $this->load->view('auth/admin_gejala',$data);
      
    }